# Metrics of extraordinariness

Tags: discussion

In the use of the principle "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence", what might constitute metrics of how extraordinary a claim is?

Sagan, Carl (writer/host) (December 14, 1980). "Encyclopaedia Galactica". Cosmos: A Personal Voyage. Episode 12. 01:24 minutes in. PBS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Prior probability given our existing body of knowledge

It is useful to consider a [Bayesian prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) on the probability of a proposition being true.

In simplified terms, this means to consider all the research that has already been done and ask, "how many of our currently accepted theories would have to be overturned if we accept this new claim?"

If the new claim/observation is consistent with many of our previous theories, only requires the discarding of one theory that itself was actually not yet the consensus view, and there already happens to be a competing theory that doesn't conflict with the new claim, then that is not a very extraordinary claim or observation, relatively.

That there is water ice on Mars is not a relatively extraordinary claim.

However, if the new claim would require overturning all of the standard model of physics and relativity, that is a much more extraordinary claim, and the scientific community would require much stronger evidence.

That homeopathy works is a very extraordinary claim.

## Science based medicine

Steven Novella emphasizes this importance of prior probability in the term that he coined, "[Science based medicine](https://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/about-science-based-medicine/)". By "science based", he means that the conclusions of a study should take into account a Bayesian prior, not simply look at whether a significant difference was observed in a study's samples.

## Establishing the prior

One difficulty in using a Bayesian prior is that reasonable people can disagree about the prior probability, especially when the claim doesn't implicate previous scientific research because Bayesian probabilities are by definition a measure of subjective belief. For example, the claim that "aliens are currently visiting the Earth", is consistent with all our scientific knowledge, but is still generally considered an extraordinary claim. Why? Because if you make some estimates of the prior probabilities of the things that would be necessary in order for that claim to be true (intelligent life exists elsewhere, it close enough to Earth, it possesses right technology available, they choose to remain hidden, etc.) for broad ranges of those estimates, the outcome is a very low probability. If people disagree about the prior probability, they can at least pin down their disagreement to *why* they disagree about that prior probability.

## Alternative hypotheses

Another aspect of this approach is that it allows for and encourages the consideration of an alternative hypothesis. In addition to considering the prior probability that aliens are currently visiting Earth, for example, you would also consider the prior probability that people are experiencing perception and memory errors as an explanation for their reported experiences.